# MS 2010 Access Primary Key changes upon DB publication to the web?

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2010, primary-key

I am quite new to MS Access 2010 and so I have some issues I don't quite understand...

I have an MS Access 2010 DB that I have published to a Sharepoint 2010 server. I noticed that when I publish my DB to the web, the primary key on my main table (and main form) gets changed.

I have googled and searched on here to find an answer but no one has been able to answer why upon publishing a DB to the web causes the primary keys to change.

Example:

Primary key ID Num BEFORE web publication:

```
                  ID Num: 11111 
                  ID Num: 22222
                  ID Num: 66666
```

Primary key ID Num AFTER web publication:

```
                  ID Num: 1
                  ID Num: 2
                  ID Num: 3
```

Why does this happen?

My subforms rely on the PK ID Num 11111, 22222, 66666 to display the information associated with it in the other tables but because the PK gets changed (to an autonumber it seems), my forms aren't properly displaying the correct information in the web published version of the DB.

I also noticed some of my other columns of data gets changed from ##### to ##,### format in the web published DB. It's quite odd. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto numbers do change when publishing to SharePoint. However auto numbers are abstract meaningless numbers. They have no meaning to the user.  So you really don’t have to care if such numbers change.

I mean, when you load a word document into computer memory, sometimes it might load into memory segment 456 and the next time you load that document into memory it might load into 89845 memory location.  So the memory location of your word document ALSO does not matter and is NOT something for the user to see or even know about, or even care about.

As a user, autonumbers have NO meaning. They are internal house keeping numbers that really you never have to care about.

Read the #7 from the Ten Commandments of Access:
http://access.mvps.org/access/tencommandments.htm

## 7 7.Thou shalt not use Autonumber if the field is meant to have meaning for thy users.

Of course this issue has nothing to do with Access, but that of relational database theory and HOW THE WHOLE industry has worked for 30+ years.

If you have other related tables, then  you need to setup relations correctly BEFORE you up-size that data to SharePoint. As long as your tables are correctly related, then any autonumbers that are changed during an up-sizing of data will ALSO force the child tables and their foreign keys to be modified to the correct and new PK.

However, if you don’t have relations setup correctly, then during a up-size then PK’s as you note are changed, but the tables you failed to relate WILL NOT be updated nor will the up-sizer “know” to make such changes. So you need to ensure relations are setup correctly.

Once relations are setup, then again you not care or worry if PK values are changed, since then any child record “FK” will also be correctly updated during the up-load process.

How to setup related data and up-size tables is outlined in this video of mine:

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL27E956A1537FE1C5&feature=plcp

Choose the second video in above - Migrating tables to office 365

Comment: Hi Albert, this didn't exactly answer my issue but it led me down the right path and I eventually got my stuff working the way I wanted it to. Thank you for your guidance!